# Compare the values of duplicate rows in Python with OpenPyXL (Long post for context; sorry.)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Long-time SE user, first-time poster. I need help with a Python project my friend has hired me for, being as I'm mainly a pentester and I only know a little programming for when it's needed during a pentest. The objective of the project is this:
We have an Excel workbook containing one worksheet. Within this sheet there are a few thousand rows, each with a name and most containing a phone number, email address, and a website. Some of the names occur twice with differing phone numbers and email addresses.
I need to take the phone and email values of duplicate rows in the Excel spreadsheet and write those values to the first row where those names occur if

- The first row number/email cell is blank
- The first row contains a toll-free number which is not capable of SMS (meaning it has one of the area codes 888, 877, 866, 855, 844, 833, or 800)
- The first row contains a non-personal/business email address (anything other than Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail/Outlook/AOL/MSN, etc.) and the second one does not.

After this process is completed, all of the duplicate rows must be deleted. So far I've written 3 functions:

- filterAC(), which creates two arrays based on the area code; one for preferred numbers (numbers that aren't toll-free) and one for non-preferred numbers (toll-free).
- filterDN(), which creates two arrays based on the domain name of the email address; one for preferred email addresses (personal emails) and one for non-preferred email addresses (anything other than those listed in the emailDomains variable).
- indexDuplicates(), which creates two arrays; one for the names of original rows, and one for the index (row number) of any duplicate rows.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def usage():
    print("[-] Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + " <document>")

    exit()

if (len(sys.argv) != 2):
    usage()

filename     = sys.argv[1]
workBook     = load_workbook(filename = filename)
workSheet    = workBook["Worksheet Name"]
areaCodes    = [888, 877, 866, 855, 844, 833, 800]
emailDomains = ["@gmail", "@yahoo", "@ymail", "@outlook", "@hotmail", "@aol", "@msn", "@me."]

unwantedRows, rows, nonPrefNum, prefNum, nonPrefEmail, prefEmail = []

def filterAC():
    for row in workSheet.rows:
        name = str(row[0].value)
        num  = str(row[10].value)

        for char in ["+11", "+1", "+", "(", ")", "-", ".", " "]:
            if (char in num):
                num = num.replace(char, "")

        ac = num[:4]

        if ("," in num):
            num = num.split(",", 1)[0]

        if (name != "None"):
            for i in areaCodes:
                itr = str(i)

                if (itr in ac):
                    nonPrefNum.append(str(num))

                else:
                    prefNum.append(str(num))

def filterDN():
    for row in workSheet.rows:
        name  = row[0].value
        email = row[9].value

        if (name != "None"):
            for i in emailDomains:
                if (i in email):
                    prefEmail.append(email)

                else:
                    nonPrefEmail.append(email)

def indexDuplicates():
    for index, row in enumerate(workSheet.iter_rows(max_col = 1, min_row = 2), start = 1):
        subList = []

        for cell in row:
            subList.append(cell.value)

        if (subList not in rows):
            rows.append((subList))

        else:
            unwantedRows.append(int(index + 1))

def main():
    filterAC()
    filterDN()
    indexDuplicates()

try:
    main()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n[-] CTRL+C detected; exiting")

    exit()
```

Any help on where I can go from here or how I can make my code function better would be extremely appreciated. Thank you.

The code I've posted so far works, I just need more code/recommendations on where to go from here.

Comment: Do the processing outside of the loop in a database or a dataframe. For the rest, you should provide clearer examples.

Comment: @CharlieClark I thought about going more in-depth but the post is already pretty long as it is. Can you provide an example of how I can go about implementing your recommendation?